# GCM Intent service OnRegistered is not getting called

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have created a GCM Intent service and the device is getting registered successfully. I also receive the REGISTRATION Intent, but the OnMessage or OnRegistered methods are not getting called.

Below the log i see.

```
07-23 06:24:23.542: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(1168): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
07-23 06:24:23.542: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(1168): GCM IntentService class: com.app.demo.myApp.GCMIntentService
07-23 06:24:23.581: V/GCMBaseIntentService(1168): Acquiring wakelock
```

Below is the code for OnMessage.

Could someone pls help me as to why the OnRegistered or OnMessage is not getting called.

```
 public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {



    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String device_id = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
        GSLogger.Log("mess_received", device_id);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String arg1) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String device_id = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
        GSLogger.Log("registered", device_id);

    }

}
```

Manifest Code:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-configuration android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
     <permission android:name="com.app.demo.myApp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" 
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.app.demo.myApp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Receiver Code in Manifest:

```
<receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
             <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
              <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
              <category android:name="com.app.demo.myApp" />
          </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.app.demo.myApp.GCMIntentService" />
```

Pic of My Package:
[image]

Comment: Show me your manifest.xml code

Comment: Updated the manifest code. 
Since i can see the GCMBroadCastReciver's OnReceived Log, i feel there should be no problem in Manifest.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The issue is

```
<service android:name="com.app.demo.myApp.GCMIntentService" />
```

Just give

```
<service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
```

And place your GCMIntentService Java file in the folder as specified by your package name in manifest.

For example if you have declared com.app.demo.myApp as the application package name

Place your GCMIntentService in the same folder structure.

Comment: When  i remove the package name from serice, i get registration error
Registration error: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED

Comment: have you added the GCMIntentService at the proper package location?

Comment: I placed it in the same package under src folder like all other .java files..  Is that the correct location?

Comment: Under src folder, you should create a package exactly as the package name of your appliaction package declared in manifest and then place the GCM Intent Service Java file there

Comment: Added a pic of my package. No luck still

Comment: Yes it looks fine, it should work .What error are you getting now?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34028/discussion-between-raghav-and-nargis)

Comment: Nargis nailed the answer.... This worked for me.. but in emulator i get AUTHENTICATION_FAILED error, since it din have a google account.. This worked like charm in device.

Comment: Thats insane, why can't I put it in any package I'd like and make it work from there :S frustration at the best

Comment: it works, I didn't add the intent service in the manisfest, my bad.

Answer (score 2):

I see some potential problems with your manifest, though I'm not sure whether they are the cause to your problems :

The following is not required :

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
```

You already have the correct C2D_MESSAGE permission :

```
 <permission android:name="com.app.demo.myApp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" 
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.app.demo.myApp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

In addition, GCM is supported from API level 8, so you probably shouldn't specify `android:minSdkVersion="7"`

Comment: Some example projects had the two permissions repeated and redundant. Good point, removing the second one seemed to fix my problem

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you put your GCMIntentService in the main folder..don't put it under any sub folder, and it will work. I had the same issue and it started working.

Comment: This is what I found too but why the hell..?